# StackPanel with Images in ScrollViewer don't shows images

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, scrollview

I'm downloading a lot of pictures from IsolatedSotrage and displaying them on the screen in a StackPanel. When I start the app I don't see the images in my phone (photos are not visible(why?!)), but when I lock the phone and unlock I have all the pictures, everything is ok.

Why this is happening?

XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer1">
    <StackPanel x:Name="myStackPanel"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

C# - Adding images to StackPanel:

```
Image[] myImage = new Image[30];

for (int n = 1; n < 30; n++)
{
    myImage[n] = new Image();
    myImage[n].Source = getBitmap(n, "/image/");  
    myStackPanel.Children.Add(myImage[n]);       
}
```

Method to open images from IsolatedStorage:

```
public BitmapImage getBitmap(int n, string path)
{
    BitmapImage myBitmap = new BitmapImage();

    using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if (store.FileExists(path + n.ToString() + ".jpg"))
        {
            using (var isoStream = store.OpenFile(path + n.ToString() + ".jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                myBitmap.SetSource(isoStream);
                return myBitmap;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return myBitmap= null;
        }
    }
}
```

At this moment I have 2 disappointing solution to this problem:

When I remove the ScrollViewer I don't have any problem, but my images is outside the screen.
But when I use the Grid and I hold each picture in a separate Grid it works, but loading images takes much longer

```
Image[] myImage = new Image[30];

for (int n = 1; n < 30; n++)
{
    Grid myGrid = new Grid();
    myImage[n] = new Image();
    myImage[n].Source = getBitmap(n, "/image/");
    myGrid.Children.Add(myImage[n]);
    myStackPanel.Children.Add(myGrid);
}
```

**Edit:**

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What's containing the `ScrollViewer` intially? Is it in something that has sufficient height to show images?

Comment: ScrollViewer is in LayoutRoot the whole screen is used to display the pictures. ScrollViewer initially contains only stackpanel.

Comment: In what method are you calling the code you posted to populate the StackPanel?

Comment: What type of element is being used to host the `StackPanel` though? Add a `Border` containing the StackPanel so you can see how the size of the `StackPanel` should be changing as the images are loaded.

Comment: In StackPanel I want use only image (*.jpg). My english is very poor so I don't understan well what I do with this Border :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when the images are added inside the `StackPanel` they get no width or height. You can verify this by adding the following and the images should be visible (this sets to full width):

```
myImage[n].Width = 480;
myImage[n].Height = (float)myBitmap.PixelHeight / myBitmap.PixelWidth * 480;
```

Altought I would probably recommend you to use a `ListBox` instead of a `StackPanel` inside a `ScrollViewer`. This can be done with the following XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListbox" />
```

And change the code to add the images (also you were skipping index 0 in this loop):

```
Image[] myImage = new Image[30];

for (int n = 0; n < 30; n++)
{
    myImage[n] = new Image();
    myImage[n].Source = getBitmap(n, "/image/");    
}
myListbox.ItemsSource = myImage;
```

In some cases you might also need to turn of delayed creation, this is done with setting `CreateOptions` on the bitmap.

```
BitmapImage myBitmap = new BitmapImage() { CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None };
```

Comment: Why would you use a `ListBox`? If selection isn't important, it adds unnecessary overhead. I wouldn't put it in a `ScrollViewer` either as it has one inside.

Comment: Ofcourse my point was to replace both the stackpanel and the scrollviewer by just a listbox. Also reason for suggesting a ListBox was because it gave the wanted result easily (showing images with full width over each other), but yes it might give a small overhead which another solution might not have.

Answer (score 1):

`BitmapImage` has an `ImageOpened` and `ImageFailed` event. Add handlers to those events and debug - see if the `ImageFailed` event is being fired, and if so, why.